# Cocoa invoke Service, do not overwrite Pasteboard

Tags: service

I have created a Service in Cocoa which grabs the selected Text and sends the result back to my Main App, so i can handle it there ( Couldn't find any other way to get current selection), now that the Service works and appears in the Service Menu, i tried to invoke the Service from my parent App to get current selection, after some goggling around i found this snippet:

```
NSPasteboard *pboard = [NSPasteboard pasteboardWithUniqueName];
    [pboard declareTypes:[NSArray arrayWithObject:NSStringPboardType] owner:nil];
    NSPerformService(@"PCB", pboard);
```

This one works as far as it triggers my Service, the Problem here is it redefines the NSPasteboard, so my service doesn't get the selected text, but a NIL Value Pasteboard which is blank, how can i prevent this?

And does someone know how to convert a .service bundle into an .app bundle that performs itself and sends the data and kills itself after finish?

thx for help

Answer (score 0):

You want to get the text that is selected in another application, right? Probably in the front application, while your app is in the background.

For this to work, you'd have to have the Service be invoked by the front application. If you invoke it from your app in the background, it can't access the front app's text field that contains the selected text. Instead, it'll try to find a text field in your own app's responder chain (I believe – someone correct me if I'm wrong on this detail).

But for your code to run in the app's process, you'll have to inject it somehow, which is - out of security concerns - mostly prohibited by OS X, and especially with sandboxed apps.

There are ways to accomplish code injection, one that 1Password and other popular tools use it through an osax extension. But that's an entirely different topic.

Once you have your code running inside the other app's process, you should be able to copy the selected text (provided it's a Cocoa app) with `[NSTextView writeSelectionToPasteboard:types:]`. I haven't tested this myself, though, so this is just an assumption.